# Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm just following some tutorial how to upload documents via spring. So while working on it i faced above issue. Since there are many questions related to same question i refer them and tried everything but none corrected m problem. In advance i don't need to add @Repository for my Repository interface and @EnableJpaRepositories in my Application class as i have use correct package sequence. For more reference refer https://dzone.com/articles/spring-spring-boot-and-component-scan. Please help me out.

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.project.abhishek")
public class DocumnetwebApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DocumnetwebApplication.class, args);
}}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class DocumentController {

@Autowired
private DocumentRepository documentRepo;

@RequestMapping("/displayUpload")
public String displayUpload() {
    return "documentUpload";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public String upload(@RequestParam("document")MultipartFile multiPartFile, @RequestParam("id")long id) {

    Document document = new Document(); 
    document.setId(id);
    document.setName(multiPartFile.getName());
    try {
        document.setData(multiPartFile.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    documentRepo.save(document);

    return "documentUpload";
}}
```

**Bean**

```
@Entity
public class Document {

@Id
private long id;
private String name;
@Lob
private byte[] data;
//getters and setters}}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document, Long> {}
```

**Application properties file**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8083
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.context-path= /documentweb
```

**pom file**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**Package Structure**

```
com.project.abhishek---application class  
com.project.abhishek.controller  
com.project.abhishek.entity  
com.project.abhishek.repository
```

Comment: Can you show me sprint boot version you are using ?

Comment: yaa sire its 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: I have used your same structure,same code, same spring boot version and same dependencies and it works for me, can you clean your project by rebuild or mvn clean install then check might be some jar corrupted..

Comment: Did everything you mentioned clean maven and update it but still same result should i create a new project.

Comment: you may, before that can you please remove .m2 then again do mvn clean install

Comment: Please post a full stack trace of your error and it is better not to use snapshot versions unless you are testing out a specific feature which isnt GA.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your same structure,same code, same spring boot version and same dependencies and it works for me, here are couple of things you can do as might be some jar corrupted.

1. Clean your project then update
2. Or remove `.m2 repositories` then run `mvn clean install`

if either do not work.

1. Create new project from scratch
2. If it does not even work then will recommend to reinstall IDE.